Does “using” instead of “by using” cause a dangling participle?
I know that it is quite common to use “using” instead of “by using”, but when it comes after a noun, I was wondering whether this technically causes a dangling participle. For example:

“You can transfer your funds to a bank using new software.”

Are you using new software to transfer funds to the bank, or is the bank using new software?

A comma in "You can transfer your funds to a bank, using new software” might help. But logic makes it clear that you are somehow using the software.

I assume you want to know whether this is wrong/bad/ugly. Rather than rehash the debate about dangling participles see this question.

"Technically" is of limited value. Perhaps a much better question is whether such a construction can create actual misunderstanding. In this example it seems unlikely, but I could imagine others that might ("the police ran a search to find criminals using spy software"?).

This isn't really a dangling participle, it's just a possible ambiguity. It's possible for the prepositional phrase to modify two different phrases. It could modify the simple noun "bank", or the verb phrase "transfer your funds to a bank".
Sometimes this can be truly ambiguous, so it may be best to reword. For example:

You can use the new software to transfer your funds to a bank.

or

You can transfer your funds to a bank that's using the new software.

But usually the context will make it clear which meaning is intended. If the sentence is found in a description of software used by banking customers, it has the first meaning. If it's in a discussion of upgrades to software used by banks, the second meaning implies.
